# Performing math in Python parser of ArcGIS field calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcmap, field-calculator

I never used python but now I need a code to do this calculation:

I'm doing this:

```
math.atan(math.fabs( !Y2! - !Y1!)/math.fabs( !X2! - !X1!) )*(180/math.pi)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you do something like:

Pre-Logic Script code:

```
def mathFunction(y1, y2, x1, x2):
  return math.Atan(math.fabs(y2-y1) / math.fabs(x2-x1)) * (180/math.pi)
```

Field = (on the bottom)...populate with your fields for y1,y2,x1,x2

```
mathFunction(!FIELDY1!, !FIELDY2!,!FIELDX1!,!FIELDX2!)
```

See [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html) on the math module.

[image: Here is a screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for atan2 ? It's precisely meant to deal with this signs mess.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.atan2

Comment: I'm looking for atan